# HTML5 Audio Tag in Safari

Tags: html

I have a question about the  tag in Safari. I have a page with many audio players on it and have set preload="none" so that page loads faster. In all other browsers, there is no text inside the player, but Safari (5.1.7, Mac) shows the text "Loading..." in the player. I personally don't mind it, but I know it will confuse users who think they should be waiting for something to download and may never click the play button.

Is there a way to set that text to something else, or even better, hide it completely?

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this is something that Safari does by default and can't be changed. However, you could use some sort of jQuery HTML5 player and add a function to display the "loading" text only when the audio is buffering.